# Cannot Fill Textbox with Javascript After Editing

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, textbox

I have a simple drop-down box and I am successfully using Javascript to automatically fill a textbox when a drop-down item is selected.

Once I edit any of the textbox's automatically filled text, or use a "Clear" button to erase textbox, the drop-down list no longer replaces fills the textbox.

How can I continue to use the drop-down box once the user has altered the textbox?

[JSFiddle Version](http://jsfiddle.net/dmccall/kchRh/400/)

**HTML code:**

```
<select id="dropdown" onchange="preset();">
    <option value="">Select a person:</option>
    <option value="Abe" >Abe</option>
    <option value="Bob" >Bob</option>
    <option value="Cal" >Cal</option>
    <option value="Dan" >Dan</option>
</select>

<input type=Submit value="Clear" onclick="document.getElementById('mytext').value='';">

<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
function preset() {
    document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML=document.getElementById("dropdown").value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `innerHTML` in one place, and `value` in another. Using `value` in both fixes it.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/kchRh/402/)

Answer (score 0):

Update the submit button to this:

```
<input type=Submit value="Clear" onclick="document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML='';">
```

Comment: That does solve it, but there's no need to use `innerHTML` here over `value`. No HTML needs to parsed.